# How to convert golang bytes to solidity bytes?

Tags: go, solidity

I have a contract in which there is a function that receives bytes as input, which are then decoded into a structure:

```
struct SomeStruct{
...
}

function Decode(bytes memory data) public pure returns(SomeStruct memory){
...
}

function TestDecode(bytes memory data) public{
  SomeStruct memory strc = Decode(data)
  ...
}
```

I also have a golang function to which I want to send a structure encoded in bytes. I will convert the structure to bytes using the solsha3 module:

```
type SomeStruct{
...
}

func(s *SomeStruct) Encode() ([]byte, error){
 typ := abi.MustNewType("tuple( ... )") //structure fields
 return typ.Encode(s)
}
```

After I have converted the struct to bytes, I want to pass the bytes to the contract as an argument, but I get revert.

How to correctly pass bytes as contract argument?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the abi library EncodePacked()

For example:

```
struct SomeStruct{
...
}

func(s *SomeStruct) Encode() ([]byte, error){
 typ := abi.MustNewType("tuple( ... )") //structure fields
 return abi.EncodePacked(s)
}

// Encoded bytes as arg

TestDecode(bytes memory data) public{
  SomeStruct memory strc = Decode(data)
  ...
}
```